# could not export component in react ||TypeError: instance.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs

hellow, i was trying export class base component in app.js of my react app, but i got an error saying **TypeError: instance.render is not a function**,

**Navbar.js**

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
class Navbar extends Component {
    rander(){
        return(
            <div>
            <h1> hellow world </h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Compoment/Layout/Navbar'

function App() {
  return (
    <div >
      <Navbar />
   </div>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: this is the error that i am get in my browser]

Comment: Maybe because your method is named `rander`?

Comment: thank you so much you saved lots of my time

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```js
import React, { Component} from 'react';
class Navbar extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <h1> hellow world </h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```